# How to move (or switch) a vertical scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

How can I  move (or switch) a vertical scrollbar?

I have a scrollbar in my div but I want to have a scrollbar on the right side next to "Panel 2" .

CSS style ***position: fixed*** and ***margin-right*** cannot be used. Is there another way (jQuery)?

I want this:

[image]

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/pahezuzohi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **wrapper** for content and set the width for content **div**.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class='left bar'>Panel 1</div>
    <div class='left menu'> Menu 1</div>
      <div class='content'>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. Integer lacinia. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Cras pede libero, dapibus nec, pretium sit amet, tempor quis. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Praesent dapibus. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. Etiam quis quam. Nunc auctor. Nulla est. Proin pede metus, vulputate nec, fermentum fringilla, vehicula vitae, justo. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et, interdum suscipit, sollicitudin et, dolor. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
       </div>
     <div class='right bar'>Panel 2</div>
     <div class='right menu'>Menu 2 </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
    .main {
        overflow-y: scroll; /* add "overflow-y: scroll" here */ 
    }
    .menu{
        background: lightgreen;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20%;
    }

    .bar{
      background: lightblue;
      float: right;
      height: 100%;
      width: 10%;
    }

    .left{
      float: left;
    }

    .right{
      float: right;
    }

    .content{
      position: relative;
      width: 40%;   /* set the width */ 
      height: 100%;
      float: left /* set the float */ 

    }
```

**CHECK DEMO:**
https://jsbin.com/niyetopaxo/1/edit?output

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are looking for:

```css
.content {
  height: 190px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

#scrollable {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#text {
  margin: 0px 210px;
}

.panel1,
.panel2 {
  background: #ADD8E6;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu1,
.menu2 {
  background: #90EE90;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.menu1,
.panel1 {
  float: left;
}

.menu2,
.panel2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div id="scrollable">
    <div id="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. Integer lacinia. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Cras pede libero, dapibus nec, pretium sit amet, tempor quis. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Praesent dapibus. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. Etiam quis quam. Nunc auctor. Nulla est. Proin pede metus, vulputate nec, fermentum fringilla, vehicula vitae, justo. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et, interdum suscipit, sollicitudin et, dolor. Nullam sit amet magna in magna gravida vehicula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Phasellus et lorem id felis nonummy placerat. Mauris elementum mauris vitae tortor. Integer lacinia. In sem justo, commodo ut, suscipit at, pharetra vitae, orci. Sed vel lectus. Donec odio tempus molestie, porttitor ut, iaculis quis, sem. Cras pede libero, dapibus nec, pretium sit amet, tempor quis. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Praesent dapibus. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Fusce aliquam vestibulum ipsum. Suspendisse sagittis ultrices augue. Etiam quis quam. Nunc auctor. Nulla est. Proin pede metus, vulputate nec, fermentum fringilla, vehicula vitae, justo. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et, interdum suscipit, sollicitudin et, dolor. 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel1">
    Panel 1
  </div>
  <div class="menu1">
    Menu 1
  </div>

  <div class="panel2">
    Panel 2
  </div>

  <div class="menu2">
    Menu 2
  </div>
</div>
```